# 正規表現でエラーがでるのですが、後読みの固定幅について教えていただきたいです。

Tags: python, 正規表現

## 問題

スクレイピングをしていまして、以下のデータから「新宿」を抜き出したいです。

```
<td>1</td>, <td class="stationName"><a href="http://www.jreast.co.jp/estation/station/info.aspx?StationCD=866">新宿</a></td>, <td>355,778</td>, <td>419,608</td>, <td>775,386</td>, <td>△ 1.8</td>,
```

そこで、[こちら](https://www-creators.com/tool/regex-checker?r=(%3F%3C%3D(%3Ctd%20class%3D%22stationName%22%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22.*%22%3E))(.*%3F)(%3F%3D%3C%2Fa%3E))の正規表現チェッカーで作成した正規表現を確認しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そして、取得できることを確認したあとに以下のコードを実行しました。

```
import re
data = '<td>1</td>, <td class="stationName"><a href="http://www.jreast.co.jp/estation/station/info.aspx?StationCD=866">新宿</a></td>, <td>355,778</td>, <td>419,608</td>, <td>775,386</td>, <td>△ 1.8</td>'

r = re.findall('(?<=(<td class="stationName"><a href=".*">))(.*?)(?=</a>)', data)
```

すると`findall`で以下のようなエラーがでます。

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-a625cd10ed2c> in <module>()
      1 # station_name_list = []
----> 2 r = re.findall('(?<=(<td class="stationName"><a href=".*">))(.*?)(?=</a>)', data2[0])
      3 
      4 for num in r:
      5   station_name_list.append(num[1])

4 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/sre_compile.py in _compile(code, pattern, flags)
    180                 lo, hi = av[1].getwidth()
    181                 if lo != hi:
--> 182                     raise error("look-behind requires fixed-width pattern")
    183                 emit(lo) # look behind
    184             _compile(code, av[1], flags)

error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

正規表現に慣れておらず、後読みの固定幅の設定が必要なのですが、どのようにすればいいのかわかりませんでした。

わかる方教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Python の正規表現エンジンでは後読みで不定長の正規表現を使う事はできません。固定長の部分だけに後読みを使ってもよいかと思いますが、`'(?<=(<td class="stationName"><a href=")).*?">(.*?)(?=</a>)'` この場合は先読み・後読みを使う必要もなさそうなので `'<td class="stationName"><a href=".*?">(.*?)</a>'` としてもよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。先読み後読みをなくして行いました。

Answer (score 1):

先読み後読みする必要がなかったため以下に変更したところ動きました。

```
import re
data = '<td>1</td>, <td class="stationName"><a href="http://www.jreast.co.jp/estation/station/info.aspx?StationCD=866">新宿</a></td>, <td>355,778</td>, <td>419,608</td>, <td>775,386</td>, <td>△ 1.8</td>'

r = re.findall('<td class="stationName"><a href=".*?">(.*?)</a>', page)

# 新宿と表示
```